# Colorbox fade in content smoothly

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

I have this problem: I use colorbox to make those jQuery popups ([colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox)). The problem is that I want to fade in the content smoothly via ajax without that loading div which you can see right before the content shows up.

When I disable the loading div via opacity it is gone, but I can't fade in my content smoothly. It just pop-ups suddenly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".register_link").colorbox({
        initialWidth:'886',
        initialHeight:'410',

        fixed:'true',
        scrolling:'false',
        transition:'fade',
        onOpen: function(){
             $("#colorbox").css("opacity", 0);
                },
        onComplete: function(){
             var title = 'Register';
             $('#cboxTitle').text(title);
             
             $("#colorbox").css("opacity", 1);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `animate()` function, instead of the `.css()` function

```
onComplete: function(){
     var title = 'Register';
     $('#cboxTitle').text(title);

     $("#colorbox").animate({"opacity": 1});
}
```